# Bounding $\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{|\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})t|}{2\sin\frac{1}{2}t}$ below by $\frac{4}{\pi^2}\log n$

Tags: real-analysis

I am working through some examples in my book on Dirichlet's formula and more specifically, Dirichlet's kernel, $D_n(t)$. Here is how the book shows that the lower estimate is $\frac{4}{\pi^2}\log n$. There are some steps where I don't follow what the author does. After each step in parentheses I will state how I think the author is proceeding to each step.

\begin{align*}
&\frac{2}{\pi}|D_n(t)|\mathop{dt}\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{|\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})t|}{2\sin\frac{1}{2}t}\mathop{dt} \text{ (by definition of Dirichlet's kernel)}\\
&\geq \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{|\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})t|}{t} \mathop{dt}\text{ (follows from the fact that } \sin\theta\leq \theta \text{ for }\theta\in[0,\pi])\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{(n+(1/2))\pi}\frac{|\sin x|}{x}\mathop{dx}\text{(Don't know; some sort of change of variable?)}\\
&\geq\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{n\pi}\frac{|\sin x|}{x}\mathop{dx}\text{(Interval has been reduced; integrand is positive so less area)}\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{(k-1)\pi}^{k\pi}\frac{|\sin x|}{x}\mathop{dx}\text{(Don't know; why is there a summation now?)}\\
&\geq\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k\pi}\int_{(k-1)\pi}^{k\pi}|\sin x| \mathop{dx}\text{(Multiplying the summand by a number less than 1)}\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\text{(Don't know; integral is } 2 \text{ if } k \text{ even, but integral is } -2 \text{ if } k \text{ odd}; \text{ is the absolute value preserved, since then } |2|=|-2|=2? )\\
&\geq\frac{4}{\pi^2}\log n\text{(Don't know; why is }\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\geq \log n?)\end{align*}

If someone could explain what is happening in the steps that I don't understand (the ones that start with "Don't know" in the parentheses), it would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: From which book is this?

Comment: Carothers' *Real Analysis*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 4 "don't know"'s in your post. I will explain them one by one:

1. Change of variable $x=(n+\frac{1}{2})t$
2. Either you or the book missed the denominator $x$. The integral is only separated into $n$ parts.
3. Since $|\sin{x}|$ is positive, in each interval, it is the same as $\int^{\pi}_0 \sin{x} dx$, whose integral is 2.
4. Yes. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29.